# i am getting zero values of longitude and latitude in google maps in android studio

Tags: java, android, google-maps

Here is my `MapsActivity.java` code, I am getting zero values for longitude and latitude after placing a marker on map and after calling `getCurrentlocation()`. What is going wrong?

```
public class MapsActivity extends FragmentActivity implements
        OnMapReadyCallback,
        GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks,
        GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener,
        GoogleMap.OnMarkerDragListener,
        GoogleMap.OnMapLongClickListener,
        View.OnClickListener {

    //Our Map
    private GoogleMap mMap;

    //To store longitude and latitude from map
    private double longitude;
    private double latitude;

    //Buttons
    private ImageButton buttonSave;
    private ImageButton buttonCurrent;
    private ImageButton buttonView;

    //Google ApiClient
    private GoogleApiClient googleApiClient;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);
        // Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready to be used.
        SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);

        //Initializing googleapi client
        googleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                .addApi(LocationServices.API)
                .build();

        //Initializing views and adding onclick listeners
        buttonSave = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.buttonSave);
        buttonCurrent = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.buttonCurrent);
        buttonView = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.buttonView);
        buttonSave.setOnClickListener(this);
        buttonCurrent.setOnClickListener(this);
        buttonView.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        googleApiClient.connect();
        super.onStart();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        googleApiClient.disconnect();
        super.onStop();
    }

    //Getting current location
    private void getCurrentLocation() {
        mMap.clear();
        //Creating a location object
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            // TODO: Consider calling
            //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
            // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
            //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
            //                                          int[] grantResults)
            // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
            // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.
            return;
        }
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            // TODO: Consider calling
            //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
            // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
            //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
            //                                          int[] grantResults)
            // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
            // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.
            return;
        }
        Location location = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(googleApiClient);
        if (location != null) {
            //Getting longitude and latitude
            longitude = location.getLongitude();
            latitude = location.getLatitude();

            //moving the map to location
            moveMap();
        }
    }

    //Function to move the map
    private void moveMap() {
        //String to display current latitude and longitude
        String msg = latitude + ", "+longitude;

        //Creating a LatLng Object to store Coordinates
        LatLng latLng = new LatLng(latitude, longitude);

        //Adding marker to map
        mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                .position(latLng) //setting position
                .draggable(true) //Making the marker draggable
                .title("Current Location")); //Adding a title

        //Moving the camera
        mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latLng));

        //Animating the camera
        mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(15));

        //Displaying current coordinates in toast
        Toast.makeText(this, msg, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        mMap = googleMap;
        LatLng latLng = new LatLng(-34, 151);
        mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(latLng).draggable(true));
        mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latLng));
        mMap.setOnMarkerDragListener(this);
        mMap.setOnMapLongClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnected(Bundle bundle) {
        getCurrentLocation();
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult connectionResult) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onMapLongClick(LatLng latLng) {
        //Clearing all the markers
        mMap.clear();

        //Adding a new marker to the current pressed position
        mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                .position(latLng)
                .draggable(true));
        String msg = latitude + ", "+longitude;
        Toast.makeText(this, msg, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


    }

    @Override
    public void onMarkerDragStart(Marker marker) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onMarkerDrag(Marker marker) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onMarkerDragEnd(Marker marker) {
        //Getting the coordinates
        latitude = marker.getPosition().latitude;
        longitude = marker.getPosition().longitude;

        //Moving the map
        moveMap();
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if(v == buttonCurrent){
            getCurrentLocation();
            moveMap();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

GetLastLocation only returns a location if one is available.  99% of the time it won't be.  Use requestLocationUpdates or requestSingleUpdate to ensure a location is acquired (note both of these are asynchronous functions, as getting a location takes time).

Answer (score 1):

Use Request Location Updates better

```
 protected synchronized void buildGoogleApiClient() {
        mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                .addApi(LocationServices.API)
                .build();
        mGoogleApiClient.connect();
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnected(@Nullable Bundle bundle) {

        mLocationRequest = new LocationRequest();
        mLocationRequest.setInterval(15 * 1000);
        mLocationRequest.setFastestInterval(1000);
        mLocationRequest.setSmallestDisplacement(0);
        mLocationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);

        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
                android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
                == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, mLocationRequest, locationListener);
        }

    }

 LocationListener locationListener = new LocationListener() {
        @Override
        public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
                mLastLocation = location;
                //do whatever you want here 
            }
        }
    };
```

Don't Forget to add onDestory Method

```
 @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        if (mGoogleApiClient != null && mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()) {
            LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.removeLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, locationListener);
            mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();
        }
    }
```